# Sympy: evaluate multivariate function at point returned by solver

Tags: sympy, substitution

I would like to evaluate a multivariate function at point returned by a solver:

```
F=x*y+x*y*z-2*y*z
solutions=nonlinsolve([diff(F,x),diff(F,y),diff(F,z)],[x,y,z])
```

which gives

```
⎧⎛ 2⋅z       ⎞⎫
⎨⎜─────, 0, z⎟⎬
⎩⎝z + 1      ⎠⎭
```

Now I want to evaluate `F` at this point, but I do not find a convenient way to use the result from `nonlinsolve` with `subs`, or a way to build a dictionary of `Symbol: point` pairs from the result of solver.

*EDIT -* Following a question, I have considered this: One possibility would be to construct with a loop over the variables the dictionary `{x:s[0],y:s[1],z:s[2]}` where `s` is `solutions.args[0]`, in order to call:

```
F.subs({x:s[0],y:s[1],z:s[2]})
```

However I do not know how to iterate on the variable names from the data of `[x,y,z]` to produce this. *End of edit*

Any suggestion?

Comment: @ngoldbaum: I am not sure the page you refer to is appropriate as this is not a request to find a bug ("a problem caused by [my] code") but a request for a technique to reach a purpose. I am now providing one way forward, although editing the question too much in this direction would make it an XY question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is `zip`,

```
vars=[x,y,z]
F=x*y+x*y*z-2*y*z
solutions=nonlinsolve([diff(F,x),diff(F,y),diff(F,z)],vars)
statiopoints=zip(vars,solutions.args[0])
F.subs(statiopoints)
```

The ouptut of `zip` is actually not in a dictionary format, it is

```
⎡⎛    2⋅z ⎞                ⎤
⎢⎜x, ─────⎟, (y, 0), (z, z)⎥
⎣⎝   z + 1⎠                ⎦
```

but this is also accepted by `subs`.